# Group by week separately for year

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-grouping

I have to group my sql query by week. But the record contains many years data. I used the query `SELECT datepart(week, myDate) as week`. But under the week 1 it shows data from every year
[image]

How to group the weeks again having the same year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT datepart(week, myDate) as week, datepart(year, myDate) as year, ... from table group by concat(year, '-', week);
```

Comment: It might be a good answer, but it were even better if you could add some explanation.